# Is having a question with high views and low votes common?

Tags: discussion, voting, badges

I recently earned the Famous Question badge [10k views] for [App Store "An Unknown Error Has Occurred", Apple Support fix was only temporary. How fix permanently?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63911/app-store-an-unknown-error-has-occurred-apple-support-fix-was-only-temporary)

I note that there are still low votes on both the question, the answer, and a hackintosh specific answer. Is this a known phenomenon within Apple.SE or the entire SE family of sites?

I am not complaining here, I asked and answered my own question. I am proud that it is viewed often. I hope that means people are searching, finding my question, and getting the answer they need.

Comment: Yes, it's happened here before. I have a "Famous Question" with three votes. More than your one, but still that means that 9,997 people read it and decided not to vote for it :-)

Comment: Does the SE api provide a means to query for questions with more than a certain number of views and show the vote totals? This is close: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search#order=desc&sort=votes&views=10000&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?page=19&tab=votes&q=views%3a10000%20closed%3ano

Answer (score 5):

This is, I believe, a systemic problem with the user base of Ask Different*. Sites like Stack Overflow, where the approach to Q&A was pioneered and little better ingrained in the user base, don't seem to have it quite as bad as we do**.

We attract a lot of search queries for problems and solutions that would otherwise have lead people to more traditional Q&A type stuff: MacWorld, blogs, traditional forums, etc. We have great content here that covers a wide range and great depth of subject matter, so we pull a good deal of search traffic from these topics. Unfortunately, the people looking for answers to these topics tend to not be greatly familiar with our Q&A approach: if you like something, vote it up. We get a lot of "thank you" type posts and comments we have to clean up as mods -- which is pretty clear indicator if you ask me that people visiting here often don't get that you don't write a thank you, you say thanks by clicking the upvote button.

So how do we solve this problem? That, I'm afraid, I have no good answers for.

```
* Completely speculative, I have no hard data for this.
** Also speculative, don't press me for data 'cause I'll crumble under scrutiny here.
```

Comment: This may not be isolated to Ask Diffferent, search for >10000 not closed, sorted by votes at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=views%3a10000%20closed%3ano

The top hit as 6k votes and 300k views.

Answer (score 4):

Given [these search results](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?page=6&tab=votes&q=views%3a10000%20closed%3ano%20score%3a..3), I would say that the phenomenon is far from rare.

There are 288 posts with at least 10,000 views with a score of 3 or lower. My cutoffs were arbitrary there, but you can play with the parameters and see that there are many posts with lots of page views and low scores.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=views%3a10000%20closed%3ano - > 10000 views then go to the "votes" sort order. The highest vote count is 296 for a question with 233k views!